# A reference to could not be added ´. An assembly must have a dll or exe extension in order to be referenced

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have plain c# console application (.NET 4.6) where I want to reference a .NET Core Class Library:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.4": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

And I get the following exception:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Simple solution:**

My .NET console application uses **.NET 4.6** and should reference a Core Class Library using **.NET Platform Standard 1.4**.

[Mapping the .NET Platform Standard to platforms](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms) says that .NET 4.6 is compatible with **.NET Platform Standard 1.3**.

Changing the project.json of the Core Class Library to (excerpt)

```
"frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

solved the problem.

[Here](http://andrewlock.net/understanding-net-core-netstandard-and-asp-net-core/) is a compatibility table demonstrating the problem (.NET 4.6 is compatible with .NET Platform Standard <= 1.3):
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Visual Studio 2015 - I can reference the output assembly of the .NET Core library, but I can't add the actual VS project as a reference