# .Net Core and .Net Framework Incompatibility

Tags: .net, .net-core

I just happened to create a .Net core library by mistake (I intended to create a .net windows library) and after writing some code in there, tried to reference it in the main project. But no - I get an error "A reference to 'Interfaces' could not be added. An assembly must have a 'dll' or 'exe' extension in order to be referenced". So went on to research more about .net core and found that it is meant for cross platform.

Did I miss something? Can the reference be even added? Or No?

If it is cross platform - only for deployment, migrating existing projects would be next to impossible - unless - whole years worth of project time is dedicated to achieve just this. So much of existing code cannot be used. Correct me if the understanding of referencing mechanism is wrong. My understanding is that the libraries cannot refer each other both ways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A reference to could not be added ´. An assembly must have a dll or exe extension in order to be referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341147/a-reference-to-could-not-be-added-%c2%b4-an-assembly-must-have-a-dll-or-exe-extensio)

Comment: If your intent is to have a .NET Framework library, why not just move the logic out of a .NET Core library and into a .NET Framework library?

Comment: Only .NET Standard class libraries are shared. You can check my blog post for details, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff

Comment: Nice post Lex. Very Interesting read. Thanks for the post!! Maybe you should add the above as your answer!! So while creating new project under 'Windows' we now have many more class library types. And the ones which you mentioned in the blog are also gone... The build env is changing so quick!! :) I see the following options now - 'Class Library', 'Class Library (Portable)', 'Class Library (Portable for iOS, Android and Windows)', 'Class Library (.Net Core)'.

Comment: Lex, please add your content in the answer section and I'll mark it as an accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Lex is what I was looking for. However since I am posting the answer myself, I'' not be able to acccept the answer. Just for records:

Only .NET Standard class libraries are shared. You can check my blog post for details, [blog.lextudio.com/…](https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff) – Lex Li yesterday

Thanks!